# VCsrepo specifying ssh key to use

Tags: svn, module, puppet

I am trying to write a module in which puppet will be fetching an SVN repo and i want it to use a specific key in order to fetch the repository. How can I specify a ssh key to in SVN VCSrepo?

On [the documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) it says we can use vcsrepo for managing ssh keys but there isn't any example for SVN on how to do it at [their website](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a little confusing, to be sure. The documentation states

> When your source uses SSH, such as 'username@server:…', you can manage your SSH keys with Puppet using the require metaparameter in vcsrepo to ensure they are present.

This implies that you manage the key through an independent resource, e.g.

```
file { '/home/svn-user/.ssh/id_rsa': ... }
```

As to your question, the [documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo#features) doesn't look very promising, sadly:

- there is a `ssh_identity` feature, but it is only present for the `git` and `hg` providers
- for those providers, you can use the `identity` parameter to specify your key

I'm not sure about the reasoning behind excluding `svn` from this feature. This seems like a valid question to the puppet-dev mailing list or the `#puppet-dev` IRC channel on Freenode.

Comment: Yeah so looks like as of now the VCSrepo doesn't support identity, i tried it and get error for svn.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Perhaps `svn` is supposed to just rely on the key that naturally belongs to the `user` doing the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it requires stepping outside of Puppet and configuring the Subversion client with a custom tunnel protocol. Basically, in `~/.subversion/config` put something like this:

```
[tunnels]
ssh_user_<remote_user> = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -l <remote_user> -o IdentityFile=<ssh_identity_file>
```

I wrote about how to do it [on my site](http://wcooley.github.io/puppet/puppet-vcsrepo-svn-user.html).