# Fetching SVN Repo with Puppet VCSrepo using svn+ssh

Tags: svn, puppet

So i want to write a module with which I can setup an SVN repo on all the clients which call the master. In order to fetch the repo i have to use svn+ssh. Right now how my module runs is:

+I have setup readonlyuser for SVN repo.
 +When puppet runs as sudo on the client it gets the private key for that user from puppet master and puts it in root/.ssh/, so that i can get the repo with svn+ssh on my client with VCSrepo

Is this a good approach? I know its kind of weird that i will be putting the private key for readonlyuser on all the clients which i will be setting up with my module.

Please suggest if i can follow a different approach.

PS
I am not good with puppet and still trying to learn :)

Comment: If the below answer was helpful to you, please consider voting and accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the approach is fine for working around your [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270285/vcsrepo-specifying-ssh-key-to-use).

To avoid making the `svn` private key the default identity of the `root` user, you can

1. Create an svn-client user with a `user` resource
2. Supply the private key to that user and
3. Make the `vcsrepo` run `svn` as that user by supplying the [user](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo#parameters) parameter

Comment: So do you mean i should have same svn user setup on all the clients who will be used by vcsrepo to get the repository?

Comment: If you don't want `root` to do all the `svn` interaction, then yes, that is what you should do.